# How do I use a .txt file for a Label's multi line text input in Kivy?

Tags: python, string, text, kivy, label

I am most of the way through making a weather app and am stuck trying to so something as simple as creating a multiline text field with Kivy. I wont import the whole program because its much too big, but ill try show the relevant code.
What my program is doing, is finding relevant lines of text from specific live weather reports and displaying them to the user. Depending on the user's location and weather, there could be as many as 8-9 lines of text down to as little as 3 lines. There MUST be a new line for each input and the line lengths vary. I'm writing all the lines needed from their variables to a .txt file and then assigning that .txt file to the text field of my Kivy label.

I have tried prepending \n to the start of each variable as I write it, which writes the text file exactly as I want it displayed in the app. I have tried appending \n to the end of each variable as I write it so it writes as one long line with \n between them.

What is happening when I assign the .txt file to the label's text field is that I'm getting only the first line printed (either way I write the .txt file).

I have tested to see if copy and paste the text file into the text field and obviously add "" around it, and strangely it works perfectly. I'll show some of what I'm doing.

This is just the Label I'm using out of several widgets in that screen.

Results1screen.kv

```
Label:
    id: strip_1
    pos_hint: {"top": .5, "center_x": .5}
    size_hint: 1, .4
    font_size: '12sp'
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.texture_size[1]
    text_size: root.width, None
    halign: "auto"
    valign: "center"
    text:
```

an example of a .txt file I've written.

the_strip_1.txt

```
ETA: 230600z or 1600 local\nBECMG 2302/2303 16010KT 9999 SHOWERS OF LIGHT RAIN SCT045\nINTER 2301/2307 5000 SHOWERS OF MODERATE RAIN BKN020
```

just the thing I'm doing in my main.py file to assign to the kivy label.

my main.py

```
    read_strip_1 = open("the_strip_1.txt", "r")
    read_strip_1_read = read_strip_1.read()
    read_strip_1.close()
    strip_1 = self.root.ids["results_1_screen"].ids["strip_1"]
    strip_1.text = read_strip_1_read
```

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong here, or what I could do to make this work...
Thank you.

Comment: can you print `print(strip_1.text)`?

Comment: Yes, and I get ETA: 230600z or 1600 local.. Which is just the first line

Comment: that means you file has only one line, can you open and check?

Comment: I checked and all my lines were in there. I don't know why it would do that. I will maybe try store all required lines in a variable by appending. Then convert back to a string, I'll see how that goes

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? This would be much easier to debug if you posted a [mcve].

Comment: Hi John, my apologies for not adding a working example, I thought it may be a simple fix for someone more experienced than me. I managed to get around the problem by storming all the lines I needed into a variable and then sending the content to the kivy page.